# How to activate the depth camera for AVCapturePhotoOutput()

Tags: swift, iphone, avfoundation, lidar

I'm trying to [follow this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth) tutorial to capture a depth map using a depth camera via AVFoundation. (I'm testing on an iPhone XR.)

But when calling

```
let vsession    = AVCaptureSession()
let photooutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
print("photo", photooutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported)
```

the output is `False`.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to enable somehow enable this for this camera? Or does depth require a special camera that this phone doesn't have?
Is depth computing using LiDAR, then, or by some other means?

Answer (score 1):

LIDAR isn’t available on iPhone XR

> iPhone 12 Pro or later

> iPad Pro 11-inch (3rd generation) or later

> iPad Pro 12.9-inch (5th generation) or later

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_depth_using_the_lidar_camera

iPhone XR is 2 years behind the lowest supported model.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone

Comment: But I think the iPhone XR [does have](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP781?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) a **TrueDepth** camera. The tutorial I mention makes no mention of LiDAR.